# can not get output of shell script to java code

Tags: java, shell

I'm running one command through shell script, so whatever the data that shell script is giving, I need to print in java code, To achieve this I'm executing below shell script through Java. But whatever the **$data** getting from shell script is printed in java. Can anyone help me?

**Below is my adb.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

REPO_DIR=/home/jagadeesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
cd ${REPO_DIR}
data= adb shell logcat | grep testing_aws
echo $data
```

Below is my java file: here I'm executing the shell script

```
String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-C", "/home/jagadeesh/Desktop/automation/Adb_logs/adb.sh"}; 

StringBuilder output2 = new StringBuilder();

try {
    Process procScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);

    procScript.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procScript.getInputStream()));

    // System.out.println(reader);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {

        output2.append(line + "\n");
        System.out.println(output2);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The script may be is throwing an error. Read the `procScript.getErrorStream()` instead and see if there is any error.

Comment: Try this command on the command line: /bin/bash -C /home/jagadeesh/Desktop/automation/Adb_logs/adb.sh
and see if it works the way you want it.

Comment: @KrassiEm same command working when i hit from command prompt. But from java only its not printing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `abd.sh` change `data= adb shell logcat | grep testing_aws` to

```
data=`adb shell logcat | grep testing_aws`
```

Please find the code which worked for me

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Script {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String cmdScript = "/home/abd.sh";

                StringBuilder output2 = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    Process procScript =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);
                    procScript.waitFor();
                    BufferedReader reader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procScript.getInputStream()));
                    // System.out.println(reader);
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {

                        output2.append(line + "\n");
                        System.out.println(output2);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

}
```

abd.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

data=`cat /home/new.ldif|grep dn`
echo $data
```

Output

```
bash-3.00$ java Script

dn: dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net
```

Comment: data=`adb shell logcat | grep testing_aws` THIS IS THE EDITED CHANGE. But not working. Nothing is printed

Comment: i have tried the same, can you try with my adb.sh file and let me know?

Comment: Hi, actually if i run some other commands like `ls -l` and `pwd` etc... then those outputs are printing, only the `adb shell logcat | grep testing_aws` is not printing the data, But if run this command from terminal then data is coming perfect. Any idea about this?